# Set Values in JAVAFX table view -objects with another object

Tags: java, object, javafx, properties, tableview

My **DTO** Object contain another two objects. I need to set the value of those also in to the table.

**controller.java**

```
package controller;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDatePicker;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import dto.AppointmentDTO;
import dto.DoctorDTO;
import dto.PatientDTO;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;


public class AddAppointmentController implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    private TableView<AppointmentDTO> tblView;

    private ObservableList<AppointmentDTO> tblData;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        tblData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        tblView.getColumns().get(0).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("appointmentID"));
        tblView.getColumns().get(1).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("appointDate"));
        tblView.getColumns().get(2).getColumns().get(0).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("patientName"));
        tblView.getColumns().get(2).getColumns().get(1).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("patienAge"));
        tblView.getColumns().get(2).getColumns().get(2).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ContactNumber"));
        tblView.getColumns().get(3).getColumns().get(0).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("doctorName"));
        tblView.getColumns().get(3).getColumns().get(1).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("hospital"));

        tblData.add(new AppointmentDTO(12, "201", new PatientDTO(2, "uh", 12, "hj"), new DoctorDTO(4, "ghj", "ghj")));

        tblView.setItems(tblData);
    }

}
```

**AppointmentDTO.java**
And this is fully encapsulated class.

```
package dto;
  public class AppointmentDTO {   
        private int appointmentID;
        private String appointDate;
        private PatientDTO patientDTO;
        private DoctorDTO doctorDTO;
    }
```

**PatientDTO** is fully encapsulated with these properties;

```
    private int patienID;
    private String patientName;
    private int patienAge;
    private String ContactNumber;
```

**DoctorDTO** is also fully encapsulated with these properties;

```
private int doctorID;
private String doctorName;
private String hospital;
```

Comment: As an aside, I think your code would be much cleaner if you put `fx:id`s on the table columns and referenced them directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do, for example,

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<AppointmentDTO, String> patientNameColumn ;

// ...

public void initialize() {

    // ...

    patientNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
        new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getPatientDTO().getPatientName()));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: i tired it. But this error comes. I don't know why is it and how to fix it.

Comment: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    SimpleStringProperty cannot be converted to ObservableValue<CAP#1>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?

Comment: Wow.. that worked. That means everu column must be initialize with variable names. Thank you

Comment: @kasun That's probably a good idea anyway. You wouldn't want everything to break because you decided to reorder the columns in the FXML file, or because you added a new column not at the end, etc.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.turais.de/how-to-custom-listview-cell-in-javafx/) link out

It's for `ListCell`, but I think you can easily apply it to `TableView`.

Maybe the code from [this](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/) project may help as well.

Comment: You should really use a cell *value* factory for this, not a cell factory. It's the value (i.e. data) you need to specify