# CellValueFactory not populate data with inner object in property (JavaFX )

Tags: javafx, tableview

I populate Employees pojo in TableView colums. 
 Employer contains rate property, that contains  doubleDomainObject which not populate in tableView.
Implementation of comboBox i not showing because it good working with CellFactory. It is desirable to focus with CellValueFactory.

### DoubleDomainObject

```
public class DoubleDomainObject extends DomainObject {
private SimpleObjectProperty<Double> doubleValue =new SimpleObjectProperty(this, "doubleValue", null);

public Double getDoubleValue() {return doubleValue.get(); }
public SimpleObjectProperty<Double> doubleValueProperty() {return doubleValue;}
public void setDoubleValue(Double value) {this.doubleValue.set(value);}
}
```

---

### ColumnDoubleComboBox

```
public class ColumnDoubleComboBox extends ColumnWrapper{
  protected TableColumn<DomainObject, DoubleDomainObject> column;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public ColumnDoubleComboBox(Bulder builder) {
      super(builder);
      this.column =  new TableColumn<>(columnName);
      setCellValueFactory();
     setCellFactory();
    }

  public void setCellValueFactory(){
      column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

### Employees

```
public class Employees extends DomainObject {

private SimpleObjectProperty<DoubleDomainObject> rate =new 
    SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "rate", null);


public DoubleDomainObject getRate() {
   return rate.get();
}

public SimpleObjectProperty<DoubleDomainObject> rateProperty() {
   return rate;
}

public void setRate(RatePerHour rate) {
    this.rate.set(rate);
}
}
```

---

### ---Сlient code---

```
tableViewWrapper = AppNode.NodeBuilder.create()
        .<Employees>createTableViewWrapper()
        .setDataMapper(this.dataMapperFabric.getEmployeesDataMapper())
        .setColums(
columnFabric.createColumnDoubleComboBox(ColumnWrapper.Bulder.create()              
.setColumnName("RATE").setColumnSize(0.2).setPropertyName("rate")
                       .............................etc
        );
```

Comment: Can you create an example that doesn't rely on the proprietary infrastructure code (builders, etc) that you have? It's pretty much impossible to diagnose this, or create an answer that would be useful for anyone else, from the code you've posted. Assuming the objects in the table's `items` list have a `rateProperty()` method, this should give you something (though it might not give it to you formatted the way you want).

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309376/set-values-in-javafx-table-view-objects-with-another-object/46310301#46310301

Comment: Thanks for your answer.